# When will Sitemap be available for Spartacus storefront?

Tags: sitemap, spartacus-storefront

Can someone please tell me whether Sitemap is planned for 5.0? Because I can't find this information in current roadmap.

I could not find this information in current Roadmap

Comment: If it's not in the roadmap, it's probably not being considered yet.

Comment: Hi Muthu. You might want to generate a sitemap yourself. However it's tricky. It requires backend-frontend coordination and some script to generate all the routes. More details here: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/14340